# Initialization problem with 16F877A in C

Tags: pic

I have some experience with PIC micro controllers ASM. But decided to move on to C. Having installed MPLABX IDE V3.55 and with the C compiler XC8. I now try to realize a program for PIC16F877A.

After initialization I try to set some output ports but there is no reaction in the simulator. When I try to change a port setting with a stimulus there is also no reaction. Where is the mistake?`

```
// Set PORTA and PORTE to digital 
    ADCON1 = 0B00000111;
   // Turnoff PORTA comparitors
    CMCON  = 0B00000111;
   // Set I/O PORTE
    TRISE  = 0B00000111;
   // Set PORTB to input
    TRISB  = 0B11111111;
   // Initialize temperature routine varables.
   //  minLimit = 0;
   //  MaxLimit = cycleTime;
   // The switches SW1 - SW5 are pulled up against VDD
   // When unpressed RE2 must be high
   // Enter button SW3 open
    PORTEbits.RE2 = 0x01;`
```

Even in watch I can not change the value.
I can change the value in SFR.

Is it possible that I run into the R-M-W cycle problem?

Comment: You've set RE2 as an input in TRISE - so trying to set PORTEbits.RE2 to some value isn't going to do much. That old PIC doesn't have separate PORTx & LATx registers for reading & writing, so you do need to be more aware of RMW, but I don't think that's your issue here...

Comment: Which simulator are you using? Proteus ISIS?

Comment: I am using the simulator that comes with MPLABX.